# n_jobs got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, image, cluster-analysis, k-means, clustering-key

I have a parameter in k-Means clustering. how do i resolve this error to solve the problem in clustering? I tried all methods but cant find the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no argument such as njobs in Kmeans.

If you want to decrease processing time, try

- initialization of clusters . USE INIT  as kmeans++
- reduce threshold for convergence in tol

Read more about sklearn kmeans  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html